# Query creator of X11 window

Tags: x11

Is there a way to ask the X Server for who created a given window? `xwininfo` and `xlsclients` don't display this information.

Comment: can you be more specific? do you mean the parent window? or the user that owns the process of a window?

Comment: The process that created the window.

Comment: Many (though not all) X11 apps set the _NET_WM_PID resource; so `xprop | grep __NET_WM_PID` may do. You can get that info with the `XResQueryClientIds` request from the [X-Resource](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/resourceproto/resproto.txt) extension, but I'm not aware of any readily installable utility making use of that.

Comment: Notice however that the X11 protocol is _still_ network transparent, and a window may be created by a remote client (ie with no pid whatsoever). There's also the case of resources (ie windows) retained after the client which created them disconnected (with `XSetCloseDownMode()`).